# Right-continuity of the augmented filtration

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory, stochastic-processes

In most books about stochastic processes, the authors write about "the usual augmentation of a filtration". I am having trouble with proving that their construction is correct, i.e. that the augmented filtration is right-continuous.

I will try to make this clear :
$\left(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P}\right)$ is a probability space with a filtration $\left(\mathcal{F}_t\right)_{t\in [0;\infty]}$, i.e. an increasing family of sub-$\sigma$-algebras of $\mathcal{F}$.

One defines the set $\mathcal{N}$ of negligibles (w.r.t. $\mathcal{F}_\infty$ and $\mathbb{P}$) by :
$$\mathcal{N}=\left\{N \subset \Omega : \exists C \in \mathcal{F}_\infty, \mathbb{P}(C)=0 \text{ and } N\subset C   \right\}$$
We say that the filtration $\left(\mathcal{F}_t\right)_{t\in [0;\infty]}$ is complete if $\mathcal{N} \subset \mathcal{F}_0$ (hence $\mathcal{N} \subset \mathcal{F}_t$ for any $t \in [0;+\infty]$).

One can always complete a filtration by considering $\overline{\mathcal{F}}_t=\mathcal{F}_t \vee \mathcal{N}$ (where $\vee$ stands for "$\sigma$-algebra generated by).

On the other hand, $\left(\mathcal{F}_t\right)_{t\in [0;\infty]}$ is said to be right-continuous if, for any $t\in [0;\infty)$,
$$\bigcap_{s>t}\mathcal{F}_s=\mathcal{F}_t$$
In the same way as before, you can "make a filtration continuous" by considering $\mathcal{F}^+_t=\bigcap_{s>t}\mathcal{F}_s$ and $\mathcal{F}^+_{\infty}=\mathcal{F}_\infty$.

The "usual augmentation" of $\left(\mathcal{F}_t\right)_{t\in [0;\infty]}$ is obtained by first, making it right-continuous and then completing it, i.e. if we denote it by $\left(\mathcal{G}_t\right)$
$$\mathcal{G}_t=\overline{\left(\mathcal{F}^+_t\right)}$$

Now, it is claimed that this usual augmentation is complete (which I am fine with) and right-continuous, which, somehow, I cannot prove despite many efforts.

I know that this question was already asked ([Right-continuity of completed filtration](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/933371/right-continuity-of-completed-filtration/1185562#1185562)) , but I think there is a mistake in its answer, which was accepted, so I thought that asking it again would be a good idea.

edit : the last link now points to a correct answer.

Comment: Do you have a link to the previously asked question?

Comment: ... and what about a look at the literature? You are not the first who is wondering about this...

Comment: I certainly hope so :) Unfortunately, I couldn't find a solution in the books avalaible to me (Le Gall, Mouvement Brownien, Martingales Et Calcul Stochastique ; Yor and Revuz Continuous Martingales and Brownian Motion and others I don't remember). If you know a good reference, that would make me very happy.

Comment: @Villetaneuse I was thinking of a theorem in Protter's book on SDEs (Theorem I.31), but it covers only filtrations generated by Lévy processes. Sorry, I'll think about it...

Comment: This is quite a pedantic question, but good for me to come across as I am starting to study stochastic calculus. The text I'm reading through right now, available on the author's website: https://www.math.wisc.edu/~seppalai/sa-book/etusivu.html states "When we develop the stochastic integral we assume the completeness. We shall not assume right-continuity as a routine matter, and we alert the reader whenever that assumption is used."