# Clarification on the Augmented Filtration

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, brownian-motion

Consider the following definition.

**Definition**.

*Let $\left(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P}\right)$ be a probability space and $W$ a Brownian motion. Let $\mathcal{F}^W_t=\sigma\left(\left\{W_s\mid s\leq t\right\}\right)$ be the natural filtration associated to $W$. The augmented filtration $\mathcal{G}^{W}$ is defined as
$$
\mathcal{G}^{W}_t=\sigma\left(\mathcal{F}^W_t \bigcup \mathcal{N}\right),
$$ 
where $\mathcal{N}$ is the family of $\mathbb{P}$-negligible events 
$$
\mathcal{N}=\left\{F\in\mathcal{F}\mid \mathbb{P}\left[F\right]=0\right\}.
$$*
Just few questions:

1. Which is the rational behind this definition?
2. I cannot see why the set $\mathcal{N}$ is to be added to the natural filtration of the Brownian motion, how is it possible to prove that it is not already included in the original filtration $\mathcal{F}^W$?
3. According to the [corresponding wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brownian_model_of_financial_markets#The_augmented_filtration), the augmented filtration is both left-continuous and right-continuous, while the natural filtration is (obviously) only left-continuous. Is it possible to find a reference for this proof?

Comment: Are you sure that the definition of $\mathcal{N}$ is correct? The standard definition is $$\mathcal{N} := \{G \subseteq \Omega; \exists F \in \mathcal{F}: G \subseteq F, \mathbb{P}(F)=0\},$$ i.e. $\mathcal{N}$ consists of all subsets of $\mathbb{P}$-nullsets. For right-continuity see this question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/933371/right-continuity-of-completed-filtration

Comment: Ok, so the crucial point here is that $\mathcal{N}$ may contain also non-measurable events.

Comment: Since the natural filtration generated by a Brownian motion (as well as other processes) is not complete, we need "enrich it" - this is known as augmenting the generated filtration, i.e. make sure that all negligible sets are included in $\mathcal{F}_0 \subset \mathcal{F}_1 \subset \cdots.$

So, in my opinion, you're really asking why is the filtration generated by the process $W$ not complete.

Comment: Yes, If I have understood correctly we need to add the $\mathbb{P}$-nullsets in order to have the right-continuity of the filtration satisfied and guarantee that the new filtration verifies the usual hypotheses 

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Usual_hypotheses

Comment: thanks for the point, I corrected accordingly.